# jQuery - how to implement handler for elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a list of elements with the same class, like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="date_time[]" class="datetime_input" />
  <input type="text" name="date_time[]" class="datetime_input" />
  <input type="text" name="date_time[]" class="datetime_input" />
  <input type="text" name="date_time[]" class="datetime_input" />
  <input type="text" name="date_time[]" class="datetime_input" />
</div>
```

And jQuery for turning a text input into `datetime picker`.

```
$(".datetime_input").datetimepicker();
```

The problem here is that if I click to the first input and set a value, then after choosing the value, this value will be inserted to all inputs with class `datetime_input`. But I would need to insert this value only to the input I clicked in.

A solution would be to add a unique ID to each input - but because I load those inputs from database, I don't know their count.

How to solve the situation?

Comment: can you post your full jQuery code here??

Comment: use $(this) instead of the class name maybe ?

Comment: which is the plugin used?

Comment: try `$(".datetime_input").each(function(){$(this).datetimepicker();})`

Comment: whether the solution worked?